# Should we put print css at bottom?

Tags: css, xhtml, print-css

Would it be better if we put print css at bottom just before `</body>` like yahoo's recommendation for js because only few people will take print and if we will put at bottom then it will be accessed after screen.css and html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Stylesheets will not block downloading like scripts will.

It's wrong in so many ways to put styles in the body.

Answer (score 3):

It will actually make your site render faster in most browsers. But the user will feel like its rendering slower. And in IE nothing will render until the stylesheet is downloaded and parsed. So, you should put it at the top (inside the `<head />` tag). If you read yahoo's recommendations that is what they say about stylesheets.

Comment: I'm talking about media="print" and it does not effect to rendering of page in browser, it will be used only if user will take print or will see print preview browser option

Comment: Yes, I saw that after I posted my answer. But you should still put it at the top of the page.